# Is there any non-interactive zero knowledge proof for Diffie-Hellman tuples

Tags: diffie-hellman, zero-knowledge-proofs, multiparty-computation

I'm aware that Zero-Knowledge for Diffie-Hellman Tuples requires 4 rounds. I wondered if there is any non-interactive version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, non-interactive ZK proofs are achieved by using a technique to transform an interactive proof into a non-interactive. For example you can use a [common reference string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_reference_string_model) or the [Fiat-Shamir heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat%E2%80%93Shamir_heuristic). If you assume pairings, then you can also use the techniques used in Groth-Sahai proofs, but I guess that doesn't apply to Diffie-Hellman tuples.